# Get an element in the document and adding child elements

Tags: jquery, html, css

I've got a set of elements called `item-group-button` in my DOM hierarchy. I use the following jQuery code to get the above specified element and append new content to the inner HTML of the element.

```
    function getMajorGroups(){
    var element = $(".item-group-button");
    $.get("http://localhost:9157/getAllMajorGroups", function(data){
        if(data.majorGroups.length != 0){
            $('.panel_list').empty();

        }
        for(var i = 0; i < data.majorGroups.length; i++){
            element[i].appendChild("<h3>" + data.majorGroups[i] + "</h3>");
            $('.panel_list').append(element);
        }
    });
}
```

The element code is as following.

```
<div class="item-group-button">
    <!-- Item Group Selection Button -->
        <h3>Beverage</h3>
</div>
```

But when I run the code, the elements don't get cleared and also the new content is appended with the current content.

What I'm trying to do is connect to a web service and according to the data received, populate the html elements. If any one have better suggestions please enlighten me!

thank you!

Comment: where is .panel_list?

Comment: it's the parent element of the item-group-button.

Comment: Is there only one panel_list and one item-groupbutton in your page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should use `.clone()` because from what I see in your code, you are appending the `element` again and again, producing some duplicate values.

```
function getMajorGroups(){
  var element = $(".item-group-button");
  $.get("http://localhost:9157/getAllMajorGroups", function(data){
    if(data.majorGroups.length != 0){
      $('.panel_list').empty();
    }
    for(var i = 0; i < data.majorGroups.length; i++){
      var clone = element.clone();
      clone.append("<h3>" + data.majorGroups[i] + "</h3>");
      $('.panel_list').append(clone);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: This worked but had to change some of the code! thanks any way! :)

Answer (score 1):

You must be getting errors in the console, there is no `appendChild` in jquery.

`$('.panel_list').appendChild(element);`

should be

`$('.panel_list').append(element);`

Comment: what is data.majorGroups[i]?

Comment: Probably post your json too that will give a good picture of what you need. Also sample out put html.